# Why can't I change char array later?

Tags: c, string

```
char myArray[6]="Hello"; //declaring and initializing char array

printf("\n%s", myArray); //prints Hello
myArray="World";  //Compiler says"Error expression must a modifiable lvalue
```

Why can't I change myArray later? I did not declare it as const modifier.

Comment: Didn't your compiler throw any warnings or even errors with this code? First of all: "Hello" is a `char const *` so its a pointer to const chars. So you should get an error about trying to change constant values. The 2nd thing is: `myArray[6]` is a lvalue(note well myArray it self isn't), so you should additionaly get a warning like " char isn't compatible with identifier of type 'char const *'" or something like that.

Comment: The short answer is because C just doesn't allow assignment to arrays. Part of the issue is that array lvalues decay to non-lvalue pointers in most contexts, including in your example. The error says that the assigned expression "must be a modifiable lvalue" and in fact it is not even an lvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `char myArray[6]="Hello";` you are allocating 6 `char`s on the stack (including a null-terminator).

Yes you can change individual elements; e.g. myArray[4] = '\0' will transform your string to "Hell" (as far as the C library string functions are concerned), but you can't redefine the array itself as that would ruin the stack.

Note that `[const] char* myArray = "Hello";` is an entirely different beast: that is read-only memory and any changes to that string is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Why redefining the array itself will ruin the stack,  can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

Array is a non modifiable lvalue. So you cannot modify it.
If you wish to modify the contents of the array, use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the name of an array cannot be modified, just use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(myArray, "World");
```

Answer (score 2):

Well `myArray` is the name of the array which you cannot modify. It is illegal to assign a value to it.
Arrays in C are non-modifiable `lvalues`. There are no operations in C that can modify the array itself (only individual elements can be modifiable).

Well `myArray` is of size 6 and hence care must be taken during `strcpy`.
`strcpy(myArray,"World")` as it would result in overflow if the source's string length is more than the destination's (6 in this case).

A arrays in C are non-modifiable lvalues. There are no operations in C that can modify the array itself (only individual elements can be modifiable).
A possible and safe method would be

```
char *ptr = "Hello";
```

If you want to change

```
 ptr = strdup("World");
```

NOTE:

Make sure that you `free(ptr)` at the end otherwise it would result in memory leak.

Comment: Thanks @alk. I changed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to an array (except when initializing it in its declaration. Instead you have to *copy* to it. This you do using [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

But be careful so you don't copy more than five characters to the array, as that's the longest string it can contain. And using `strncpy` in this case may be dangerous, as it may not add the terminating `'\0'` character if the source string is to long.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign naked arrays in C. However you can assign pointers:

```
char const *myPtr = "Hello";
myPtr = "World";
```

Or you can assign to the elements of an array:

```
char myArray[6] = "Hello";
myArray[0] = 'W';
strcpy(myArray, "World");
```

Comment: I feel it should be noted, that `strncpy(myArray, "World", 5);` only works because `char myArray[6] = "Hello";` already took care of the `0`-terminator to be in the right place, namely at `myArray[5]`.

Comment: In the first case, wherein u reassign the myPtr to "World", here notice that "Hello" is not at all changed to "World", because at any point in time pointer to sequence of char, then that entire sequence of characters which is "Hello" in your case is readonly.
Instead, "World" is another sequence of char to which now myPtr will point to.
"Hello" still remains in stack till the time stack unwinds i.e. function terminates.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign strings to variables in C except in initializations. Use the strcpy() function to change values of string variables in C.